# DataTables.AspNet IDataTablesRequest is null when posting data to WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, datatables

I am dealing with `DataTables.AspNet` nuget package to implement server-side pagination, searching and filtering.

I am trying to post my table name from ajax `datatables` to WebApi controller in order to get the specific C# DataTable to be returned as data source. I pack table name as a key-value pair of `IDictionary<string, object> AdditionalParameters` (`"table"` is a key). When the request is processed by `Data` method of WebApi controller, the `IDataTablesRequest` argument is always coming as `null` so I can't get my table name! Moreover, when I assign the table name explicitly and get `DataTable`, `DataTablesResponse.Create()` returns `null`.

So how can I force `IDataTablesRequest` to get data passed from `datatables.js`?

Client Side

```
function loadTable(type, editable) {
var url = "/api/Request/" + type;
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/Request/Columns/" + type,
    type: "GET",
    statusCode: {
        200: function (response) {
            dtcolumns = response;
            var columns = [];
            if (editable) { columns.push({ data: null, className: 'select-checkbox', defaultContent: '' }); }
            for (var i in dtcolumns) {
                columns.push(
                    {
                        name: dtcolumns[i].Name,
                        title: dtcolumns[i].Caption,
                        data: dtcolumns[i].Name,
                        visible: !(dtcolumns[i].Caption === ""),
                        sortable: true,
                        searchable: true
                    });
            }
            var request_data = new Object();
            var AdditionalParameters = {};
            AdditionalParameters["table"] = type; // Table Name!
            request_data.AdditionalParameters = AdditionalParameters;
            var table = $('#just-table').DataTable({
                deferRender: true,
                bPaginate: true,
                autoFill: {
                    horizontal: false
                },
                serverSide: true,
                processing: true,
                columns: columns,
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/Request/Data",
                    type: "POST",
                    //contentType: "application/json",
                    //dataType: "json",
                    //data: JSON.stringify(request_data),
                    data: request_data, //PASSING TABLE NAME TO WEBAPI CONTROLLER
                    statusCode: {
                        500: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseJSON.Message)
                        }
                    }
                },
                rowId: 'ID',
                scroller: {
                    loadingIndicator: true
                },
                targets: 0,
                dom: 'BS<"toolbar">frtips'
            });
        }
    }
})
}
```

Server Side

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Request/Data")]
    public JsonResult<IDataTablesResponse> Data(IDataTablesRequest request /*ALWAYS NULL!!!*/)
    {
        DataTable data = DBContext.GetInstance()[request.AdditionalParameters["table"].ToString()];
        var filteredData = data.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.ItemArray.Contains(request.Search.Value));
        var dataPage = filteredData.Skip(request.Start).Take(request.Length).CopyToDataTable();
        //ALWAYS NULL!!!
        var response = DataTables.AspNet.WebApi2.DataTablesResponse.Create(request, data.AsDataView().Count, filteredData.Count(), dataPage);
       return new DataTablesJsonResult(response, Request);
    }
```

Comment: if you don't pass any additional paramters (by commenting out this line `data: request_data`) is the `request` object still null?

Comment: @zgood unfortunatelly yes:(

Answer (score 0):

Your ajax query is GET yet the method is decorated with a POST attribute

Comment: Nope! This request is POST (look at "/api/Request/Data")

Answer (score 0):

Late to the reply, but here's my two cents worth as I had the same question.

An MVC controller cannot construct an interface as it doesn't know or understand which implementation of that interface to use.

Create a class that implements the interface and use that as the method parameter identifier.

see also: [Passing an interface to an ASP.NET MVC Controller Action method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564650/passing-an-interface-to-an-asp-net-mvc-controller-action-method)